# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException related to Dialog and Context

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context, android-windowmanager

I get this error `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException` in my crash reports. On some devices it only reports the exception but doesn't crash the app, other devices experience a crash.

It is related to how the app is displaying dialogs.

**Other answers suggest that the wrong `context` is being used, like a global one, but in my case I am not doing that, I am passing my activity's context to a different object's method.**

`public class Utils {`

contains a method

```
public static void noConnection(Context context){
    final CustomAlertDialog alert = new CustomAlertDialog(context, context.getString(R.string.ErrorPastTense), context.getString(R.string.ErrorInternet), context.getString(R.string.OkButton), null);

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            int id = v.getId();
            switch(id){
                case R.id.alertConfirm:
                    alert.dismiss();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    alert.setListener(listener);
    alert.show();
}
```

which is called by a method in my activity like this `Utils.noConnection(myActivity.this);`

the error logs show the exception as occuring at `alert.show()`

why? and how to avoid

Comment: use Context context=null as a global and context=this inside the onCreate() Utils.noConnection(context);

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are showing the dialog from a UI Thread ? Try something like:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        alert.show()
    }
});
```

Comment: hm,  it runs in `onPostExecute()` so thats definitely the UI thread but there could be another dialog still displayed in a condition. I added another `dialog.dismiss()` just before my call to the `Utils` class

Comment: You are opening a dialog from an async task ? Your context might be invalid by the time you try to open it ?

Comment: invalid? the asynctask runs in the same activity, and this message occurs if the server didn't return properly in which case I am not changing the activity or any UI elements etc, just popping up a dialog.

Comment: its inconclusive, some of my users are able to get the exception, I am not

Comment: So you say your users are still getting the exception using the code above ?